# Handling API calls and parameter packaging with fetch() in JavaScript

Tags: callback

fetch('http://localhost:8080/midterm/demoCode')
.then(function(response) {

```
return response.json();
```

})
.then(function(data) {

```
var param = {
  keyword: data.inputText
};

return callApi('http://localhost:8080/midterm/demoCode', param);
```

})
.then(function(response) {

})
.catch(function(error) {

});

How to callapi before package parameter